# Error after reinstall magento extension

Tags: magento, installation

When I tried to reinstall my Magento extension, I got this error:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Special_Settings failed: No releases for 'Special_Settings', skipping.

Then Magento has turned on the maintenance mode (file maintenance.flag to root directory of site).  Google has not answered my problem.

Comment: I have found the solution for the problem. The cause of problem was that Magento find updates on connect.magentocommerce.com/community, not on local file system. Before updates the system will turn on maintenance mode and after an error happens the system will not return to normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

simply delete the file maintenance.flag

Comment: This file is the flag of system error, not a cause. I often got global magento error after deleting this file.

Comment: I have tried to install an old extension and the installation failed (the installer tried to copy some existing files...) so the whole website stoped working, then after I deleted this file, everything get back to work